# Regex: Match all decimals but the first one

Tags: javascript, regex

What would the regex pattern be to match all decimals but the first one? I'm using javascript's replace(), and would like to remove all but the first decimal in a string.

Examples:

```
1.2.3.4.5 --> 1.2345

.2.3.4.5 --> .2345

1234.. --> 1234.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function parseAndNormalizeDecimal(dec) {
  var i = 0;
  var result = dec.replace(/\./g, function(all, match) { return i++===0 ? '.' : ''; });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I didn't even realize you could use a function there. Wow. Thanks James.